# Any ideas on what is wrong with this javascript code?

Tags: javascript, debugging, local-storage

I have the code below. The purpose of the code is to grab all the values stored in the local storage and display them in two HTML elements with `id`s of `'title'` and `'textLoc'`. `'title'` is an `<input type="text">` and `'textLoc'` is a `<textarea>`. I want the values to be stored in the `<textarea>` and the keys to be stored in the `<input type="text">`. The values are being stored correctly but the keys are not. Any ideas on why this would be?

```
var tests = [];
var titles = [];

var finalTests = "";

var key, value;
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
  key = localStorage.key(i);
  value = localStorage.getItem(key);
  tests.push(value);
  titles.push(key);
  finalTests += "<tr><td><a class=\"dashlinks\" href=\"javascript:void\" onclick=\"rememberTest("+i+")\">" + key + "</a></td></tr>";
}

for (i=0; i<tests.length; i++) {
document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = titles[i];

document.getElementById('textLoc').innerHTML = tests[i];
}
```

Comment: I'm curious what you are trying to do with the loop at bottom.  Each time through the loop it replaces the innerHTML of those items, so all you'll see is the last one.

Comment: And yes, you are replacing the value each time. May be you want to append?

Comment: @rob That was just a very small way to show what the code actually does. There is a bunch of other code that it goes through, its just that was the easiest way to summarize it. Trust me, its very useful.

Comment: @aip.cd.aish I meant to replace the value each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `document.getElementById('title').value` and `document.getElementById('textLoc').value`. Also it seems like you are doing nothing with finalTests after you store it.

Comment: ahh... thanks, wow, did not see that one. The finalTests is used later on. This code is only a snippet of a bunch of code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be appending the string to the text area:

```
document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = document.getElementById('title').innerHTML + titles[i] + '\n';
```